# How to lexically analyze Microsoft Access identifiers?

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm writing a lexer (*not* a regular expression) that needs to handle Microsoft Access-style identifiers. They can look like this:

```
myid
[myid]
[my identifier]
```

I want to handle the edge + corner cases, including identifiers containing the escaping characters `[` and `]`. I've been unable to find an online reference for the exact syntax.

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the input of this lexer? Does it have to distinguish identifiers from other symbols? Does it have to distinguish between reserved keywords and identifiers? What should the output of the lexer be?

Comment: I have a parser/lexer that recognizes a simple expression language, consisting of the usual soup of identifiers, literals, and operators. The identifiers very commonly include spaces, and I need to use a syntax familiar to the business users. The output of my lexer is a stream of (type, value) tokens which the parser consumes to make a AST; that in turn is consumed by a run-time property evaluation engine.

Comment: Is this parser/lexer written in Access VBA?

Comment: No, the code base is C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access doesn't allow identifiers with brackets. Thus, they need no escaping, and writing a lexer should be really simple. There are no escape sequences as the delimiters cannot occur in identifiers.

See [the docs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/guidelines-for-naming-fields-controls-and-objects-120c27fa-7ae1-4182-9baa-dbd183179cc3).

Btw, this is a common cause of pain when working with RDBMSes with more permissive identifier names in Access, as Access may change identifiers or cause errors when linking to tables containing identifiers that violate its rules.

Comment: After reading the docs provided, it appears there is no escape sequence for prohibited characters like square brackets. That does make my lexer very simple indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how your lexer works exactly. Therefore I just created a small quick and dirty lexer to have some code where I can embed and test the parsing of identifiers.

The brackets can be handled by the parser or the lexer. I handle them in the lexer.

I declare the following types

```cs
public enum TokenType
{
    Error,
    Identifier,
    Number,
    Etc,
}

public class Token(TokenType tokenType)
{
    public TokenType TokenType { get; } = tokenType;
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public long Number { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => TokenType is TokenType.Number ? $"Number = {Number}" : $"{TokenType} = \"{Text}\"";
}
```

This is the lexer:

```cs
public class Lexer(string input)
{
    string _input = input;
    int _index;
    char _ch;

    private void GetChar()
    {
        _ch = _index < _input.Length ? _input[_index++] : (char)0;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Token> EnumerateTokens()
    {
        GetChar();
        while (_ch != (char)0) {
            while (_ch != (char)0 && Char.IsWhiteSpace(_ch)) {
                GetChar();
            }
            switch (_ch) {
                case >= '0' and <= '9':
                    string numString = "";
                    do {
                        numString += _ch;
                        GetChar();
                    } while (Char.IsDigit(_ch));
                    if (Int64.TryParse(numString, out long num)) {
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.Number) { Number = num };
                    } else {
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.Error) { Text = "Invalid number" };
                    }
                    break;
                case '[': // === Handles brackted identifiers ===
                    GetChar(); // Skip '['
                    var identToken = GetIdentifier();
                    if (_ch == ']') {
                        GetChar();
                        yield return identToken;
                    } else if (identToken.TokenType is TokenType.Error) {
                        yield return identToken;
                    } else {
                        yield return new Token(TokenType.Error) { Text = "Missing ']'" };
                    }
                    break;
                case > ' ' and < (char)127 and not '.' and not '!' and not '`' and not ']':
                    yield return GetIdentifier();  // === Handles unbrackted identifiers ===
                    break;
                default:
                    yield return new Token(TokenType.Error) { Text = $"Unexpected character '{_ch}'" };
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private Token GetIdentifier()
    {
        string ident = "";
        do {
            ident += _ch;
            GetChar();
        } while (_ch is >= ' ' and < (char)127 and not '.' and not '!' and not '`' and not '[' and not ']');
        return new Token(TokenType.Identifier) { Text = ident };
    }
}
```

Test:

```cs
var lexer = new Lexer("10 myid\r\n[myid]\r\n[my identifier]");
foreach (Token token in lexer.EnumerateTokens()) {
    Console.WriteLine(token);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Prints:

```
Number = 10
Identifier = "myid"
Identifier = "myid"
Identifier = "my identifier"
```

Note: The docs reference Erik A gives is not clear about which character set is assumed for valid identifiers. I assumed 7 bit Ascii, but maybe it should be extended to 8-bit ANSI, or even to Unicode for for more recent implementations. However, Unicode also includes a lot of control characters with codes > 255.